# get badge Text returns blank

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, microsoft-edge-extension

I'm trying to get the badgeText of the current Tab to display that in the `popup.html`. But when I use `chrome.browserAction.getBadgeText`, i'm getting a blank value as the result even when I can see the badge text on the icon.

I'm using Manifest version 2. And added below code in popup.js file.

Below is the code i'm using:

```js
chrome.browserAction.getBadgeText({}, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Try passing the tabId in the first argument, like `chrome.browserAction.getBadgeText({tabId:thetabId}, function(result){console.log(result);});`. Also make sure you are checking the correct console.

Comment: Are you able to see other messages in the console? If not, you've probably hidden all the console messages.

Comment: Yes Yu, I'm able to see other messages. And for this code above, I see a blank line in the console.